# Array.prototype.sort() only one return statement for strings

Tags: javascript

When I use the Array.prototype.sort() method to sorteded my array with object inside it. I get the same output with only one return statement compared with 3 return statements. Why is it necessary to return three statements?

One return statement:

```js
const courses = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Node.js'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'C++'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'JavaScript'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Basic'
  }
];

courses.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
});

console.log(courses);
```

Three return statements:

```js
const courses = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Node.js'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'C++'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'JavaScript'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Basic'
  }
];

courses.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
  if (a.name > b.name) return 0;
  return 0;
});

console.log(courses);
```

Comment: MDN is your friend - [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Read the part about the `compareFunction`

Comment: Because that is how it has been defined: _"If comparefn is not undefined, it should be a function that accepts two arguments x and y and returns a negative value if x < y, zero if x = y, or a positive value if x > y."_ (Source: [ECMAScript 2015 - 22.1.3.24 Array.prototype.sort (comparefn)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort))

Comment: Its not necessary to have *3 return statements* its necessary to return something less than 0 to sort a to an index lower than b and return something higher than 0 to  sort b to an index lower than a and 0 to leave a and b unchanged

Comment: While the spec *requests* a numeric return value, is it *necessary*? Can anyone think of an array for which the single return `sort` wouldn't sort as desired?

Comment: @CertainPerformance the "problem" with his single return code *(actually both codes)* is that it doesn't differentiate between `a==b` and `a>b`. So since it is up to the browser wich sort implementaion it uses, and they are not required to be stable it could make a difference for items hat are considered "equal". Like if he would sort by `id` as he has two nodes with `id=3`

Comment: @CertainPerformance See the duplicate for an example